# javascript module import: import module what is based on react jsx syntax

Tags: reactjs, import, module, jsx

How to import JSX file in module without error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

index.html

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.15.8/babel.min.js" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="index.js" type="text/babel" data-type="module"></script>
```

index.js - in there is everything ok

```
import {SheetWaypointList} from 'test.js';

class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };

    render() {

        return <div>content 1</div>;
    };
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
});
```

**test.js - Error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"**

**NB!!! i dont want to use "React.createElement"**

```
class SheetWaypointList  extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){

        super(props);
    };

    render() {

        return (<div>sisu</div>);//THIS IS ERROR because this is not a string but jsx syntax
    };

}

export {SheetWaypointList};
```

What i have to do if i want import jsx class via "import {SheetWaypointList} from 'test.js';"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - not what i expected, but still

```
render() {

        return (html2jsx(`<div>sisu=${c}</div>`));//now it is not a error and it will replace tags
    };
```